# Unable to get incognito option in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, incognito-mode

I am not getting incognito option after adding jp@gc- chromedriver config in Jmeter. Please let me know if I have to add any dependencies.

---

[image: Jmeter]

Even After adding plugin manager jar-1.6, updating selenium/webdriver plugin, I am still not able to see incognito optionr

Answer (score 0):

There is a checkbox `Run in Incognito mode` at "Chrome" tab of the [Chrome Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/)

[image]

If you tick it - the Chrome browser will be started in [Incognito mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)

Demo:

[image]

If you don't see the checkbox make sure to upgrade your Selenium/WebDriver Support plugin to the latest available version, it can be done using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image]

Comment: After adding, plugin manager jar-1.6, updating selenium/webdriver plugin, I am still not able to see incognito option.